# Vent-free natural gas fireplace - No gas when attempting to light pilot

Tags: gas, fireplace, valve

A number of years ago, we had a vent-free gas log set installed in our fireplace.  It has always seemed to work just fine.  Normally, when we are not using it for prolonged periods, we shut the gas off to it entirely, so no pilot.

Today, I turned the main gas line to the fireplace on, then turned the knob on the gas valve to "Pilot" and held it in all the way (spring-loaded), but I did not hear any audible indication that there was gas coming out, nor could I smell any.  I attempted to depress the Pilot knob multiple times, holding it for prolonged periods sometimes.  Absolutely nothing.

I then shut the main gas line off, then disconnected the log set's gas valve from the main supply pipe.  I very slowly turned the main gas line toward it's "open" position, and it didn't take much of a turn before I did hear gas coming through that opening, so I immediately shut the main gas back off.  So the main supply isn't the problem.  There's gas coming into my supply pipe from the meter.

In the case of a natural gas fireplace log set such as this set, what might be the most likely culprit?  I've read some threads here on DIY SE that have dealt with similar situations with LP fireplace logs, but nothing specifically regarding natural gas.  It seems there are some other factors that affect these devices when they're connected to an LP supply.

I would probably be comfortable replacing the gas valve body if that was likely to be the problem, but I'm not sure how I would go about testing and diagnosing so that I could be sure that I need to spend $150 on the replacement gas valve (SIT 820 - 0820637).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I thank you for reading.